# I can't see sensitive data in mysql monitoring tools

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Good afternoon everyone. I have zabbix and also new relic.
however in both I can't see the sensitive data that in real time is being brought by the queries.

Example:
for example in the image below, directly from mysql views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3ODO.png)

Same situation in zabbix.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Qt2.png)

the question I ask is:
Is there some specific mysql configuration that I should do?

- Mysql 5.7 version in RDS Amazon.